# can't issue request get from app engine to same GAE

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, html2pdf

I have a PHP API on GAE, I'm using HTML2PDF and trying to use file_get_contents to send a pdf by mail. My request comes from an app engine instance to the same app engine (but can be another instance).

The URL to get a pdf is: "https://example.com/pdf/invoice/user_id/invoice_id/secret_token";
From a browser everything is working fine and I can see and download the document.

But if I'm doing file_get_contents('https://example.com/pdf/invoice/user_id/invoice_id/secret_token') I receive an error 500 and app engine instance is crashing. Same error using cURL.

With curl:

> Error: Server Error
> The server encountered an error and could not complete your request. Please try again in 30 seconds.

With file_get_contents:

> Warning: file_get_contents(https://example.com/pdf/avoir/2020/845/7ac639686c8129258d5752bdf0c3aeb622074c6d89a691a71070f180461c9896): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 500 Internal Server Error in /workspace/index.php on line 106

Error from google log console (error 500 on the request):

> The process handling this request unexpectedly died. This is likely to cause a new process to be used for the next request to your application. (Error code 203)

The most weird thing is that I have another endpoint for another pdf document and this one is working perfectly.

I even tried to replace all the template which wasn't working by the other one and I still got the same error. (after the replace, the only different thing was the URL).

I can read the html buffer of the template (if I exit the script before). The problem appear only on the `$pdf->writeHTML($content)` line.

I tried many user Agent with both curl and file_get_contents, tried to increase the timeout. But same error. I also tried with Postman and everything's fine.

I'm using a F1 instance but tried F2 to be sure it wasn't a memory lack.

(I know I can output html2pdf straight to base64 for emails but I need to understand why it's working only on some endpoints even if they are the same)

Thank you very much

Edit: Here is the code from index.php:

```
  case 'test-curl':
   102          die(get_data_c('https://example.oa.r.appspot.com/pdf/avoir/2020/826/2330956135b4cd945b1151724c23a13293d207df43b5c435477cb13d4c3258ed.pdf'));
   103      case 'working-test':
   104          die(file_get_contents('https://example.oa.r.appspot.com/pdf/facture/2020/14996/72724f0e57972f3db709de73ec5c0155ba03bddb1ccd437f4d5faa90bfe101c2.pdf'));
   105      case 'test-fgc':
   106          die(file_get_contents('https://example.oa.r.appspot.com/pdf/avoir/2020/845/7ac639686c8129258d5752bdf0c3aeb622074c6d89a691a71070f180461c9896.pdf',0,stream_context_create(["http" => ["timeout" => 20]])));
```

Comment: Show the code for `/workspace/index.php` Use a tool that adds line numbers to the listing such as `cat -n /workspace/index.php`.

Comment: I have edited the main post with the code